# How can I train the last few layers of RegNet-800MF backbone using PyTorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch, transfer-learning, pytorch-lightning, lightning

I am trying to get better results by allowing a few final layers of a previously frozen backbone (RegNet-800MF) to be trained. How can I implement this in PyTorch Lightning? I am very new to ML so please excuse me if I have left any important information out.

My model (MechClassifier) calls another class (ParametersClassifier) which includes the pre-trained RegNet as its frozen backbone. During training the forward function passes inputs only through the backbone of the ParametersClassifier and not the Classifying layers. I will include the init functions of both below.

My `MechClassifier` model:

```
class MechClassifier(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_classes,
        lr=4e-3,
        weight_decay=1e-8,
        gpus=1,
        max_epochs=30,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.lr = lr
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        self.__dict__.update(locals())
        
        self.backbone = ParametersClassifier.load_from_checkpoint(
            checkpoint_path="checkpoints/param_classifier/last.ckpt",
            num_classes=3,
            gpus=1,
        )
        
        self.backbone.freeze()
        self.backbone.eval()


        self.mf_classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.backbone.num_ftrs, 8),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(8, num_classes),
        )
        
        self.wd_classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.backbone.num_ftrs, 8),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(8, num_classes),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        self.backbone.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            x = self.backbone.model(x)

        # x = self.model(x)

        out1 = self.mf_classifier(x)
        out2 = self.wd_classifier(x)

        # print(out1.size())
        return (out1, out2)
```

`ParametersClassifier` (loaded from checkpoint):

```
class ParametersClassifier(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_classes,
        lr=4e-3,
        weight_decay=0.05,
        gpus=1,
        max_epochs=30,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.lr = lr
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        self.__dict__.update(locals())

        self.model = models.regnet_y_800mf(pretrained=True)
        self.num_ftrs = self.model.fc.in_features
        self.model.fc = nn.Identity()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.num_ftrs, num_classes)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.num_ftrs, num_classes)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(self.num_ftrs, num_classes)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(self.num_ftrs, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        out1 = self.fc1(x)
        out2 = self.fc2(x)
        out3 = self.fc3(x)
        out4 = self.fc4(x)
        return (out1, out2, out3, out4)
```

Comment: So you are looking to only train `mf_classifier` and `wd_classifier`, correct?

Comment: @Ivan Previously, yes I have only been training mf_classifier and wd_classifier. However now I would like to train mf_classifier and wd_classifier, plus the final few layers of the backbone (RegNet within the ParametersClassifer class).

Comment: Ok, can you show the `forward` function of `ParametersClassifier`?

Comment: @Ivan - have edited the question to show before forward steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the implementation for the [`Regnet`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.models.regnet_y_800mf.html) model you are using [`here`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/aeafa912585b5398f595a632d49a4e5925644db7/torchvision/models/regnet.py#L296). Its `forward` function:

```
def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    x = self.stem(x)
    x = self.trunk_output(x)

    x = self.avgpool(x)
    x = x.flatten(start_dim=1)
    x = self.fc(x)

    return x
```

Instead of using a `torch.no_grad` context manager as you did, you should rather switch on/off the `requires_grad` as necessary. By default module parameters have their `requires_grad` flag set to `True` which means they are able to perform gradient computation. If this flag is set to `False`, you can consider those components as frozen.

Depending on which layers you want to freeze and those that you want to finetune, you can manually do that. For example, if you want to freeze the backbone and finetune the fully connected layer of the Regnet, and replace the following from `MechClassifier`'s `__init__`:

```
self.backbone.freeze()
self.backbone.eval()
```

With the following lines:

```
## freeze all
self.backbone.model.requires_grad_(False)

## unfreeze last section of 4th block of backbone 
block4_section1 = getattr(self.backbone.model.trunk_output.block4, 'block4-1')
block4_section1.requires_grad_(True)
```

And perform inference on `MechClassifier` with a `forward` function like so:

```
def forward(self, x):
    self.backbone.eval()
    x = self.backbone.model(x)
    out1 = self.mf_classifier(x)
    out2 = self.wd_classifier(x)
    return (out1, out2)
```